# Any way of attaching .csl, .bib files by using `knitcitations` package?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

I have tried to attach `bibliography.bib, nature.csl` files by using `knitcitations` packages on `myPkg_vignette.Rmd`, but when I execute the .Rmd file, I got following error:

```
pandoc-citeproc.exe: Could not find bibliography.bib
pandoc.exe: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
Filter returned error status 1
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error
```

I looked into `knitcitations` manual and how to attach `.csl, .bib` file by handy, but I got warning and can't attach these files on `myPkg_vignette.Rmd`.

**Edit** :

This is context of `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{Vahid_Jalili_Musera_2015,
         title  = "MuSERA: Multiple Sample Enriched Region Assessment",
         author = {Vahid Jalili, Matteo Matteucci, Marco Masseroli, Marco J. Morelli},
         journal = "Briefings in Bioinformatics",
         year    = "2016",
         pages   = "1-15",
           url     = {http://bib.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2016/03/23/bib.bbw029.abstract?keytype=ref&ijkey=8IlROGziM9XA7NS},
         doi     = "10.1093/bib/bbw029 ",
}
```

How can I attach `bibliography.bib`, `nature.csl` on package's vignette easily ? I read some post in SO and I confused about the given solution. I am quite new with using `knitcitations` packages, and I may get wrong with attaching `.bib, .csl files` in right way. Can any one help me out how to address this issues in Rstudio ? Any idea ? Thanks a lot :)

**NEW EDIT** :

I've read [this post](https://texblog.org/2013/08/20/rknitr-automatic-bibliography-generation-with-biblatex-in-rstudio/) and followed the solution :

```
setwd('C:/Users/me/Documents/myPkg')
Sys.setenv(TEXINPUTS=getwd(),
           BIBINPUTS=getwd(),
           BSTINPUTS=getwd())
```

but bibliography.bib is not printed in .Rmd file. I changed the global option for weaving Rnw file to knitr. How can I print out bibliography on .Rmd file ? Any further help please ?

Comment: What happens when you just include the files in the `vignettes/` directory?  Works for my packages....

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  vignette' html file is generated, but Reference info not found. Precisely, I got this : pandoc-citeproc: reference Using not found. Why ? Initially I created bibliography.bib file by using bibtex::write.bib(). How can I overcome this issues?

Comment: Revisit what and how you are doing things. How you _write_ the .bib file should be irrelevant.   Check you are calling pandoc the right way. "Works for me" from .tex, from .Rmd and when called different ways.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I looked into some existing packages in CRAN, how people write bibliography.bib file, so I studied example from this. Honestly, I am bit of lost of your suggestion. Is that possible to give concrete answer on that ? Thank you

Comment: We write bib files "by hand", or in a proper editor.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I intend to auto generate .bib files and attach this to .Rmd file. How can I make this happen ? Plus, I edit my post with the context of bibliography.bib file. Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem. `.bib` lying in `vignettes`. Generated using JabRef. Knitting works, only R CMD check 'rebuilding of vignette outputs' errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Dirk, it just works for me.  Maybe you didn't put the YAML together properly, or maybe you never cited anything.  Here's a sample document that works with your bib file:

````
---
title: "Biblio Example"
output: html_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Here's Some Text

This text cites the paper:  [@Vahid_Jalili_Musera_2015].

## References

The bibliography will appear by magic at the end of the document, just
below this text.
````

See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html for more details.

Comment: Fom the name of the directory you used, it looks wrong.  Why would you put a vignette in "C:/Users/me/Documents/myPkg"?  They belong in the vignettes directory.  But in any case, you shouldn't use those settings when building a package, you should just put the .bib and .Rmd files in the same directory (myPkg/vignettes), and let R find them.  If you are setting those environment variables, that's likely the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did put .bib, .Rmd files in /vignette directory. I don't know why Rstudio still did not print out bibliography.bib on .Rmd file. Any further solution please ?

Comment: Did you set the environment variables?  They would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that my `.bib` file was listed in `.Rbuildignore`. Removing the entry solved the problem.

According to the `r-pkg-dev` mailing list answer from Duncan Murdoch, `.Rbuildignore` is "case-insensitively against the file and directory names relative to the top-level package source directory".

Therefore the entry `xxx.bib` ignored all `.bib` files recursively in my package directory and the error was thrown.